# Is it possible to use feature selection before training AdaBoostClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining

I am a bit new to Text Mining and Python sklearn, so hope you could help me with this problem.

Once I have used a vectorizer and feature selector using Python sklearn, I train an AdaBoost Classifier, *boosting* several classifiers. Subsequently, the accuracy scores are calculated based on a prediction the AdaBoost Classifier makes. Giving me a nice overview of the precision, recall, F1 and accuracy scores. However, once I dump the model using sklearn joblib and load it again to check if it can predict a binary text classification problem the following error is given:

```
ValueError: X has different number of features than during model fitting
```

Going through a list of tuples containing several vectorizers, classifiers and feature selectors, after which the metrics and vectorizer, classifier and feature selector are appended to seperate lists. Part of my code goes as follows:

```
for (vectorizer,vec_Name),(classifier,classifier_Name),(fselector,fselector_Name) in list(itertools.product(vectorizers,binary_classifiers,featureSelectors)):
trainText = vectorizer.fit_transform(trainText_b)
testText = vectorizer.transform(testText_b)

trainText = fselector.fit_transform(trainText,trainClass_b)
testText = fselector.transform(testText)

classifier = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=classifier, n_estimators=50, algorithm='SAMME')
cls = classifier.fit(trainText,trainClass_b)
prediction = cls.predict(testText)
precision = precision_score(testClass_b, prediction,average='binary')
recall = recall_score(testClass_b, prediction,average='binary')
F1 = f1_score(testClass_b, prediction,average='binary')
accuracyScore = accuracy_score(testClass_b, prediction)

results_b.append((vec_Name,classifier_Name,fselector_Name,precision,recall,F1,accuracyScore))
best_class_b.append((vectorizer,classifier,fselector,accuracyScore))
```

Like said before, it still calculates several scoring metrics, but is not usable to predict a certain class. Does this mean that feature selection is not feasible in combination with AdaBoost Classification?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give some names of your fselectors, vectorizers, estimators etc!

Comment: Vectorizers: TfidFVectorizer, CountVectorizer
Classifiers: Multinomial NB, BernoulliNB, Linear SVC
FSelectors: SelectKBest, RFE and ExtraTreesClassifier

All with different parameters.